# moment generating function from given PMF?

Tags: probability, statistics

I just a quick question from a book, generating Moment generating function from given PMF:
$$f(x) = \frac1n $$  where $$x \in {a, a+1, \ldots , a+n-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be our random variable. Recall that the mgf of $X$ is $E(e^{tX})$. In our case, this is
$$\frac{1}{n}\left(e^{at}+e^{(a+1)t}+e^{(a+2)t}+\cdots +e^{(a+n-1)t}\right).$$
The expression can be "simplified," for it is a geometric series with first term $\frac{e^{at}}{n}$ and common ratio $e^t$. The sum, for $t\ne 0$, is $\frac{e^{at}}{n}\cdot \frac{e^{nt}-1}{e^t-1}$.

Comment: how did u simplified that answer to $$(expat/n)⋅(expnt−1/et−1)$$

Comment: There is a typo in your solution. The MGF of a random variable X is defined as $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})$

Comment: It is a formula that you have probably seen, straightforward to prove. In general we have $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots +ar^{n-1}=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$. In using it, I reversed the signs of both top and bottom, for no good reason.

Comment: @TnilkImaniq: Thank you, fixed.

Comment: aaah igot it now. now how can i get Expected value E[X] from this?
i know if i differentiate it, but should i just simply differentiate M(t) at t=0? to get E[X]

Comment: For a discrete random variable $X$, taking on values $a_1$ to $a_n$ with probabilities $p_1$ to $p_n$, we have $E(f(X))=p_1f(a_1)+p_2f(a_2)+\cdots +p_nf(a_n)$. That's what I used, all the $p_i$ equal to $1/n$, and $f(x)=e^{tx}$. The $a_i$ go from $a$ to $a+n-1$.